# How can I measure the frame drop of a camera?

Tags: frame

I've been using LED lights controlled by Arduino to examine a camera's frame drop (30fps). Each light is on for 16ms and off for 34ms. However, because I don't know the precise timing of the LEDs turning off, I cannot be sure whether frames are dropped. The images of each frame show that the lights are alternating, when there should be some frames with no LED on at all.
Is there another, more precise method of examining frame drops?

Comment: How many frames are you examining to look for a frame with no LED?

Comment: Use a photodiode or phototransistor and measure to measure the LEDs. You can also spin a wheel and measure the RPM.